Converting ESRI FileGDB raster to vector without losing precision in QGIS
Using QGIS, I am looking to convert a raster to a vector so I can acquire the data at a polygon level to merge to another shapefile. The raster is an ESRI FileGDB format raster.
The first problem I get is:

The file won't convert using polygonize (raster to vector) if it is an ESRI (but does work if it is a TIFF).
If I do convert to a TIFF it shifts the numbers to integers. So on a zero to one scale raster, the resulting information is not useful.

The file itself is from this site https://www.gns.cri.nz/data-and-resources/aggregate-opportunity-modelling-for-new-zealand/ In the downloadable able file it is in appendix three under aggregatemodel2021.gdb titled L3_Gravel_AOM when opened in QGIS.

There is no such thing as an "ESRI" file format; there are several raster formats associated with Esri, including ASCII raster, and several binary formats which Esri implemented first, plus file geodatabase. It's not possible to generate polygons from continuous (real) raster data -- You must classify it into discrete (integer) values first.  So your actual problem is likely the command to convert FGDB to TIFF. Please [Edit] the Question to focus on that problem, specifically, the command you used to do the conversion, and the image metadata of the resulting raster.

Make sure QGIS is using GDAL >= 3.7 (when filegdb raster support was introduced).

Don't use the GDAL > Polygonize tool, use the Vector creation > Raster pixels to polygons tool which handles floating point data.


